# who/what deletes the print job?

Tags: delphi, printing, windows-xp, delphi-2010, zebra-printers

Having a strange problem where a print occasionally is not being printed

The scenario is that we print barcode labels with a barcode printer (Zebra LP2844).
Printer is plugged into the TerminalPC and then shared.

Printer->TerminalPC -> Terminal Server.
Session on TerminalServer is using Printer as \TerminalPC\Printer

When logging print Events we see the following:

```
Print OK:
1) Print OK (Event 10, User myUser)
2) Print deleted (Event 13, User NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM)

Print not OK => only Event 2) appears in the event log
```

Anybody having a clue about what is happening here?

More information:
This problems occurs about 2 out of 10 times. Only difference is an increasing ID being printed as part af the barcode.
The barcode is the only object being printed. It saves to file (*.emf) every time - and looks fine on file.
The application is developed using Delphi 2010 and works fine in all other ways.

Comment: Are you using the same user login myUser for every access to the terminal server from within the Delphi app?. This link talks about EventID: 13 in windows. You may want to check the causes and see if there is some clue there. - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=13&EvtSrc=autoenrollment&LCID=1033/

Answer (score 0):

Print jobs are removed from the print spooler by the port monitor.  The port monitor "[EndDocPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" function calls "[SetJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162978%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" with JOB_CONTROL_SENT_TO_PRINTER to indicate the the job has finished, and this removes it from the spooler.

If the printer uses a custom port monitor, the problem could be in the printer driver or custom port monitor.  If it uses a standard port such as LPT or USB, it's more likely a problem with the application not calling "[EndDoc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" consistently, or not checking return codes from EndDoc.